# ms access database with java

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

I am creating a java program, with which I am editing into a Microsoft Access Database. I have a certain case, in which I need to search if a certain record already exists in my table, if it does, I want to update it, and if not, I want to create it from scratch.

I have found this piece of code:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERID=@UID) select 1 else select
```

This code gives me an error, saying that a SELECT, UPDATE or DELETE statement was expected.

In a code that I have tried my self, I have done the following:

```
try{
            s = con.createStatement();
            s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table WHERE date='" + today + "'");
            rset = s.getResultSet();    

            if (rset.getString("date") == null){

                s = con.createStatement();     
                s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO table VALUES ('" + today + "','" + cflow + "','" + vat + "','" + cnn + "')");

            }
        }

        catch (SQLException exp)
        {
            System.err.println(exp);
        }
```

But with this code, when the record does not exist yet, the user input is not updated inside the database.

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

1st: If I can remember right, then is

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERID=@UID) select 1 else select
```

an incomplete transact sql statement -used by the sql engine from a database system.

2nd:

```
if (rset.getString("date") == null){}
```

you should avoid this way, because there is a good chance to get a Nullpointer Exception.

In my eyes a better one is a test the size of resultset for zero or the resultset it self for the value of *NULL*.

In case the UPDATE statement won't also be executed, check your SELECT statement using the database engine -Ms Access, SQL Server, etc.- directly. The advantage is you can exclude a mistake in your SELECT query.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply :)

I have already tried testing resultset for null, in fact that was the way it originally was, but didn't work. Now that I tried testing it to 0, java gave me an error saying "java.sql.ResultSet and int"..

Comment: @Brian Zammit you should not test if rset equals 0, you should test if the size/count/what they call it is 0 or bigger, if size > 0 then you have one or more rows in the database.
Why don't you do a select count(...) and check if you get 0 or something else from that?

Comment: oh yeah.. I will check into some more detail about that.. thanks.. because I never used the select count, and I am not sure on how to use it...

Comment: I just found some more info about the select count..
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0292.html
It actually seems quite easy xD.. I will give it a try..

Comment: I gave it a try, however as in some cases, the record does not exist, when I try an rs.next(), it is giving me a null pointer exception...

Comment: Sorry for the large amount of posts -.-

But I was wondering..Should I catch it in a try catch blog, so that if it creates an exception I perform an update (as that record does not exist), and if not I perform an update, because it would already exist?

Or is it bad programming style?

Comment: Actually this is the dirty way. http://nopaste.info/3e68736268.html shows an working example accessing to a database and for a testing to the size of the resultset.

Answer (score 0):

```
(rset.getString("date") == null)
```

should be

```
(!rset.next())
```

rset is positioned 'before' the first result that gets returned. next() returns true if there was a 'next' result to get.

Also, what datatype is your 'date' variable? There's no guarantee that a date.toString() will format the date correctly for MS-Access version of SQL.

Rather, prepare a statement

```
PreparedStatement ps = connetion.prepareStatement("SELECT * from table where date=?");
```

and set the date like

```
ps.setDate(1, date);
```

then issue the query using the prepared statement.

That saves any toString() issues. (I haven't compiled this, it almost certainly won't work as-is, but the idea is there).

Comment: Yeah, good point.. I feel like an idiot not having thought of this before.. however it still did not work -.- Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
SELECT IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERID=@UID) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

or

```
SELECT IF(EXISTS (SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERID=@UID), 1, 0)
```

(I'm not sure about the real syntax here.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i used to find the last ID in a table. IF the table is empty the no ID will be returned. If table is populated then i needed the next ID for new record.

> ```
> ResultSet mn = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(ExamID)FROM ExamResults");
>
> if (mn == null){
>        jTextField1.setText("1");
> } else{
>        while (mn.next()) {
>
>          int lastID =Integer.parseInt(""+(mn.getObject(1)));
>          jTextField1.setText(""+(lastID+1));
>        }
> }
> // close the objects
>
> mn.close();
> stmt.close();
> conn.close();
> ```